# Python Django error "no module named ..." after manage.py runserver. Did I organize my files correctly?

Tags: python, django, djoser

I'm new to Python and Django. I'm trying to create a user authentication system with Djoser following an online tutorial. I am getting this error "no module named "auth_system"" when I try to run the server to test the connection with Postman.

- Is it because of the way that I organized the folders that my "auth_system" file is not recognized?
- Also, is the way that I put all the files into the virtual environment folder correct?

[image: My current directory]

[image: The error that I'm receiving]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added auth_system to installed app in settings file:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'auth_system',
]

Comment: I guess he haven't load this module although installed.

Comment: in the settings.py of auth_system, the INSTALLED_APPS looks like this:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    'accounts',
]`

I think it doesn't make sense to put 'auth_system' there right?

Comment: You have to add it to the main project settings.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that the auth_system wasn't configured with postgres properly.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a quick reference for how to start a django project and review the arranged files.

1. Be sure that you have properly installed django.

   $ python -m django --version

2)Move to the folder where you will create your project and command:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

Where mysite is the name of your project.

The created files of the project mysite will look like the following:

> mysite/
> manage.py
> mysite/
> **init**.py
> settings.py
> urls.py
> asgi.py
> wsgi.py

3. Now you can test if everything is ok

   $ python manage.py runserver

> July 08, 2021 - 10:28:12 Django version 3.2, using settings
> 'mysite.settings' Starting development server at
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

4)You can add a project with the next instruction:

```
$ python manage.py startapp polls
```

The created directory polls, looks like this:

> polls/
> **init**.py
> admin.py
> apps.py
> migrations/
> **init**.py
> models.py
> tests.py
> views.py

5. Then you can create a superuser like this:

   $ python manage.py createsuperuser --username=admin --email=admin@example.com
6. Or normal users like this (in python prompt):

   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   user = User.objects.create_user('user01', 'user01@example.com', 'user01password')

Hope this useful for you!

More information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thanks, I already went through that and the server ran when I first installed and migrated to Postgres. Now that I made a new project for the authentication system its not running.

Comment: If you’re using PostgreSQL, you’ll need the psycopg2 package. Did you already install it? (Read this for more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)

Comment: Thanks, I realised that the auth_system wasn't configured with postgres properly.